# Magtek PIN pad BDK

Tags: vb.net, encryption

I have a Magtek PIN pad, I have integrated with it, and get (KSN,EPB) after the customer enters the PIN.

I have found that I need the BDK in order to decrypt the data and retrieve the clear text PIN.

How do I obtain the BDK?

Comment: KSN, EPB and BDK? You can't appeal to JFK and the CIA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **BDK** (Base derivation Key) is a super secret key that are used to derive encryption keys for payment terminals. The BDK is part of the **DUKPT** (Derived unique key per transaction) scheme as specified in **ANSI X9.24** (This is a document that costs money .. ).

Usually many payment terminals are loaded with keys derived from the same BDK, and the holder of the BDK are able to decrypt transactione/pin blocks from all such terminals. For this reason the BDK needs to be managed in [HSM's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module), and the management sorounding these keys needs to be [PCI complient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_industry) etc.

Unless you are an Issuing Bank or a Payment Gateway you should not have access to real BDK's .. and specially not thus used for PIN blocks. If you are actually an Issuing Bank or a Payment Gateway, you should already know about stuff like PCI, DUKPT, ANSI X9.24, or start reading up on this, as this ain't trivial stuff, and the consequence of not adhering to the requirements can be severe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, then I have to send the KSN and EPB to the HSM, and it will do the decryption, is it?

Comment: Why do you need to decrypt a PIN ? Are you a card issuer ? Usually only the card issuer would need to decrypt the PIN's